# Toggle Button with borderless button style - how to get background in checked state?

Tags: android, button, android-5.0-lollipop, rippledrawable

I am trying to get a standard Android ToggleButton to take on a somewhat custom style: in the unchecked state no border/background fill is displayed, in the checked state a background fill is displayed, when pressed (checked or unchecked) a ripple effect is displayed to transition from one state to another.

I've got things working, for the most part using this as my ToggleButton's background:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ripple" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checked_bg" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

ripple:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <color
            android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </item>

</ripple>
```

checked_bg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid
        android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight" />

</shape>
```

However, when I go from the checked state to the unchecked state, the ripple applies a solid fill to the button that does not match the checked button state fill color, so it appears to "jump" from one color to the next immediately.  I believe this is because I am using colorControlHighlight for both the checked state background fill and the ripple color, so the ripple ends up at the color, and starts at another, slightly lighter color...

However, I can't simply change my checked state background fill to this lighter color, since that will make the case when I check/turn on the button look odd - it will start out at the lighter color, matching the checked background fill, and end up at a darker color, and then immediately jump to the lighter color again.

Is there a clean way to handle this? Or am I stuck with a jump in color change at one end?

Alternatively I could use two different ripples, one for the pressed = true and checked = false and the other for the pressed = true and checked = true case, right?